# Using a For Loop to Change Words in Strings to List Items

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I am trying to use a `for` loop to find every word in a string that contains exactly one letter **e**.

My guess is that I need to use a `for` loop to first separate each word in the string into its own list (for example, `this is a string` into `['this']`, `['is']`, `['a']`, `['string']`)

Then, I can use another For Loop to check each word/list.

My string is stored in the variable **joke**.

I'm having trouble structuring my For Loop to make each word into its own list. Any suggestions?

```
j2 = []

for s in joke:
if s[0] in j2:
    j2[s[0]] = joke.split()
else:
    j2[s[0]] = s[0]
print(j2)
```

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845482/iterating-through-a-string-word-by-word. you can't use `for s in joke`

Comment: in future, for variable names use the symbol ` instead of " for clarity. The first implies a part of code (like variable), the second makes it look like a string

Answer (score 8):

This is a classic case for [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). To generate a list of words containing exactly one letter 'e', you would use the following source.

```
words = [w for w in joke.split() if w.count('e') == 1]
```

Comment: Do note that instead of creating a  list for every single word as you stated, it is more efficient to create a single list that contains all the words instead like in `Hans'` answer.

Answer (score 2):

For finding words with exactly one letter 'e', use regex

```
import re
mywords = re.match("(\s)*[e](\s)*", 'this is your e string e')
print(mywords)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
joke = "A string with some words they contain letters"
j2 = []
for w in joke.split():
    d = Counter(w)
    if 'e' in d.keys():
        if d['e'] == 1:
            j2.append(w)

print(j2)
```

This results in:

```
['some', 'they']
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way to do it using `numpy` which is all against for:

```
s = 'Where is my chocolate pizza'
s_np = np.array(s.split())
result = s_np[np.core.defchararray.count(s_np, 'e').astype(bool)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
mystr = 'this is a test string'    
[i for i in mystr.split() if sum(k=='e' for k in i) == 1]   
# test
```

If you need an explicit loop:

```
result = []
for i in mystr:
    if sum(k=='e' for k in i) == 1:
        result.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = "The cow jumped over the moon."
new_str = sentence.split()
count = 0
for i in new_str:
    if 'e' in i:
        count+=1
        print(i)
print(count)
```

Comment: I am not sure if that what you are looking for but that gives you how many 'e' and print the word with letter 'e'