# How to perform pattern matching between two strings?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I want to have a good pattern matching code which can exactly match between both strings.

```
x = "Apple iPhone 6(Silver, 16 GB)"
y = "Apple iPhone 6 64 GB GSM Mobile Phone (Silver)"

Approach 1:
tmp_body = " ".join("".join([" " if ch in string.punctuation else ch.lower() for ch in y]).split())
tmp_body_1 = " ".join("".join([" " if ch in string.punctuation else ch.lower() for ch in x]).split())
if tmp_body in tmp_body_1:
    print "true"
```

**In my problem x will always be a base string and y will change**

```
Approach 2:
Fuzzy logic --> But was not getting good results through it

Approach 3:
Using regex which I don't know
```

I am still figuring out ways to solve it with regex.

1. Removal of special characters from both base and incoming string
2. Matches the **GB** and **Color**
3. Splitting the GB from the number for good matching

These things I have figured out.

Comment: what is your input output?

Comment: `x` will be my base and `y` will change

Comment: Regex should only be used for input that you know the format of. It's ill-fit for this use case.

Comment: So what do you think my approach should be, as I was also thinking the same @nhahtdh

Comment: @vks could you paste some code how to perform that

Comment: You just want to check if all words in `x` are in `y` in any order.is it?

Comment: All  words in `y` are present in `x`  @vks

Comment: @vks `x` is my base string in which all new `y` needs to be matched and sorry y has currently 16 gb not 64 gb

Comment: See demo https://regex101.com/r/wF3qV0/1

Comment: "All words in `y` are present in `x`." Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181763/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-words to find the words and then do a set intersection. `set(words(x)) & set(words(y))'. This won't tell you much based on the very different strings you've provided.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/python-string-similarity-with-probability

Comment: @JanneKarila hey,I have used this approach but wasn't getting and good results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following approach. Split each into words, lowercase each word and store in a set. `x` must then be a subset of `y`. So for your example it will fail as 16 does not match 64:

```
x = "Apple iPhone 6(Silver, 16 GB)"
y = "Apple iPhone 6 64 GB GSM Mobile Phone (Silver)"

set_x = set([item.lower() for item in re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9]+)", x)])
set_y = set([item.lower() for item in re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9]+)", y)])

print set_x
print set_y

print set_x.issubset(set_y)
```

Giving the following results:

```
set(['apple', '16', 'gb', '6', 'silver', 'iphone'])
set(['apple', 'mobile', 'phone', '64', 'gb', '6', 'gsm', 'silver', 'iphone'])
False
```

If `64` is changed to `16` then you get:

```
set(['apple', '16', 'gb', '6', 'silver', 'iphone'])
set(['apple', '16', 'mobile', 'phone', 'gb', '6', 'gsm', 'silver', 'iphone'])
True
```

Comment: @JohnDene i have one question which is very much similar to your problem i.e when you need to match your base string from a database of millions of records is it possible in a way you are using ? if yes, can you please provide me database query for such operation.

Comment: What type of db you are using? I can tell you in mongodb .This result is not effective as I want but works well and million of records no problem working this theory on them @RajendraKhabiya

Comment: I am using MySQL with Apache Solr and PHP .... Your suggestions are helpful for me... Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to do longest common substring here ofntwo unknown strings.
[Find common substring between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings)

Regex only works when you have a known pattern to your strings. You could use LCS to derive a pattern that you could use to test additional strings, but I don't think that's what you want.

If you are wanting to extract the capacity, model, and other information from these strings, you may want to use multiple patterns to find each piece of information. Some information may not be available. Your regular expressions will need to flex in order to handle a wider input (hard for me to assume all variations given a sample size of 2).

```
capacity = re.search(r'(\d+)\s*GB', useragent)
model = re.search(r'Apple iPhone ([A-Za-z0-9]+)', useragent)
```

These patterns won't make much sense to you unless you read the Python re module documentation. Basically, for capacity, I'm searching for 1 or more digits followed by 0 or more whitespace followed by GB. If I find a match, the result is a match object and I can get the capacity with `match.group()`. Similar story for finding iPhone version, though my pattern doesn't work for "6 Plus".

Since you have no control over the generation of these strings, if this is a script that you plan on using 3 years from now, expect to be a slave to it, updating the regular expression patterns as new string formats become available. Hopefully this is a one-off number crunching exercise that can be scrapped as soon as you answered your question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem because the output I am getting is apple iphone 6,but on the other hand I want to match the 16 gb and silver color as awell