# how to turn string of words into list

Tags: python

i have turned a list of words into a string
now i want to turn them back into a list but i dont know how, please help

```
temp = ['hello', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day']
temp_string = str(temp)
```

temp_string will then be "[hello, how, is, your, day]"

i want to turn this back into a list now but when i do list(temp_string), this will happen

```
['[', "'", 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'h', 'o', 'w', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'i', 's', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'y', 'o', 'u', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'd', 'a', 'y', "'", ']']
```

Please help

Comment: Depending on your needs, consider splitting on spaces, or using regex to split on whitespace or word boundaries.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: `eval(temp_string)` # prints -> `['hello', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day']`

Comment: So do you want ['hello', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day'] as final output or ['[', "'", 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'h', 'o', 'w', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'i', 's', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'y', 'o', 'u', 'r', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'd', 'a', 'y', "'", ']']?

Comment: Actually, it would be more accurate to say that `temp_string will then be "['hello', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day']"`, *with* the single quotes around each word.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by evaluating the string. That's not something I'd normally suggest but, assuming you control the input, it's quite safe:

```
>>> temp = ['hello', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day'] ; type(temp) ; temp
<class 'list'>
['hello', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day']

>>> tempstr = str(temp) ; type(tempstr) ; tempstr
<class 'str'>
"['hello', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day']"

>>> temp2 = eval(tempstr) ; type(temp2) ; temp2
<class 'list'>
['hello', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day']
```

Comment: You could use `ast.literal_eval` if you are not sure about the safety of the input source.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question? [Converting a String to a List of Words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181763/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-words)

Working code below (Python 3)

```
import re
sentence_list = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
sentence = ""
for word in sentence_list:
    sentence += word + " "
print(sentence)
#output: "hello how are you "

word_list = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", sentence).split()
print(word_list)
#output: ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split on commas and join them back together:

```
temp = ['hello', 'how', 'is', 'your', 'day']
temp_string = str(temp)

temp_new = ''.join(temp_string.split(','))
```

The `join()` function takes a list, which is created from the `split()` function while using ',' as the delimiter. `join()` will then construct a string from the list.

Comment: I don't understand why the down vote? This is valid and compatible with 2 and 3