# How to detect the words with a specific letter and return them in a list containing them

Tags: python-3.x

I wan to create a function which, when given a sentence and a letter, returns a list containing all words in the sentence with the said letter. I want to use a list comprehension to return the list. The following is an expected output.

```
    sentence = "Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried 
    anything new"
    words_containing(sentence, 'a')
['Anyone', 'has', 'made', 'a', 'mistake', 'has', 'anything']
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you supply a [mcve]?

Comment: My main issue is that I don't know how to get a list of words from a sentence. I believe I have to use a str method but I am lost on which one I could utilize.

Comment: How about [Converting a String to a List of Words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181763/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-words)

Comment: list = ["abcd", "defg", "abc", "defg", ".", "a"]/n reslst = []/n for i in list:/n if i[0] == 'a':/n reslst.append(i)----- This is what I could do if I wanted to get the list from another list. My scenario however has a string instead of a list and my solution here does not use a list comprehension to return a list.

Comment: @jpp   sentence_list = sentence.split() 
    reslst = []
    for i in sentence_list:
        if i[0] == 'a':
            reslst.append(i)
    print(reslst)
            
------ This code only returns the words if they start with the letter not contain it. Furthermore, 'Anyone' is not returned as it is capitalized.

Comment: It is pretty useless to post code in comments. Why not add it to your question? My downvote stays.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_words (sentence, letter):
    all_words_list = (sentence.split())
    selected_words_list = [word for word in all_words_list if letter in word]
    return selected_words_list

print (get_words ("Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new", "a"))
```

Comment: Is there a way to make 'Anyone' return as well. It is not being returned as it is capitalized. Its case must be maintained when it is returned however. I tried casefold() before but it would cause 'Anyone' to be undercase when the list is returned. @pakpe

Comment: See the new answer above.  If this is what you were looking for, please mark is as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_words (sentence, letter):
    capital_letter = letter.capitalize()
    all_words_list = (sentence.split())
    selected_words_list = [word for word in all_words_list if letter in word or capital_letter in word]
    return selected_words_list

print (get_words ("Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new", "a"))
```