# how to remove first word of each string in the list and append those words into a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

how do i get 1st word of each string in the list and create a new list.

```
list1 = ['GenX XE','GenX XM','GenX XT','GenX XMA','GenX XTA']

# this is my my list 
n= len(list1)

for i in range(n):
    print (list1[i])
```

Output:

```
[GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX']
```

Comment: `print([i.split()[0] for i in list1])`

Comment: Take a look at `split()` method of strings.

Comment: Maybe this helps, check split().
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181763/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-words

Comment: @rakesh its indentation error: unexpected indent and I didn't understand what u suggested.

Comment: Don't use len-based iteration over lists (or other sequences) in Python. It is a strong anti-pattern. Use `for item in sequence` instead. Also don't use use number suffixes for variable names. Try and come up with meaningful names. In this case eg. "input_strings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list_comprehensions`:

```
In [1757]: n = [i.split()[0] for i in list1]

In [1758]: n
Out[1758]: ['GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX']
```

Which basically means this:

```
In [1754]: n = []

In [1755]: for i in list1:
      ...:     n.append(i.split()[0])
      ...:     

In [1756]: n
Out[1756]: ['GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX']
```

Comment: `i.split(' ')` is a bit redundant. you can save yourself the 3 keystrokes with `i.split()` :P :P

Comment: ha! fair enough :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split` and then use index to access the element. In the below example I am using list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
list1 = ['GenX XE','GenX XM','GenX XT','GenX XMA','GenX XTA']
print([i.split()[0] for i in list1])
```

**Output:**

```
['GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
In [5]: map(lambda x:x.split()[0],list1)
Out[5]: ['GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['GenX XE','GenX XM','GenX XT','GenX XMA','GenX XTA']

# this is my my list 
n= len(list1)

for i in range(n):
     print (list1[i].split()[0])
```

Note: list1[i].split()[0]

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with regex:

```
import re
import numpy as np
l = ['GenX XE','GenX XM','GenX XT','GenX XMA','GenX XTA']
r = [re.findall('(?i)([A-Z0-9]+)',x) for x in l]
```

To extract a specific information you can do:

```
np.array(r)[:,0]
```

And obtain:

```
array(['GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX', 'GenX'], dtype='<U4')
```