# Extracting numbers from a sentence in python and performing calculation on it

Tags: python, string, list, split

I'm new to Python but here is the question

Given a string, write a program to return the sum and average of the numbers that appear in the string, ignoring all other characters.

**Input**

The input will be a single line containing a string.

**Output**

The output should contain the sum and average of the numbers that appear in the string.
Note: Round the average value to two decimal places.

**Explanation**

For example, if the given string is "I am 25 years and 10 months old", the numbers are 25, 10. Your code should print the sum of the numbers(35) and the average of the numbers(17.5) in the new line.

**Test Cases**

*Input*

I am 25 years and 10 months old

*Output*

35
17.5

*The above test case is pretty straightforward and simple,my problem comes when you trying to solve something like this.*

*Input*

A girl64 35spaces numb6rs

*Output*

205
66.66

So basically what I am asking is,
how do you extract the digits thats existing between a string of characters.
To make it so that (164) does not become (1,6,4)

Comment: If you worked on this for two days you should have some code to show, please post it and explain what is the issue with it.

Comment: You need to convert the sentence into a list of string  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181763/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-words  and then you need to check for each element of the list to be digit using isdigit( ). Then covert the obtained number into integer using the int( ) function and do the average and the sum

Comment: Yes and plz show your code that you tried for two days.

Comment: your question is poorly written you need to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By the way, how does 64+35+6 adds up to 205?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
input_str = "I am 25 years and 10 months old"
num_str = re.findall('[0-9]+',input_str)
if len (num_str) > 0:
    list_str = [int(n) for n in num_str]
    print (sum(list_str),round(sum(list_str)/len(list_str),2))
else:
    print (0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments, code modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to perform.

```
string = 'I am 25 years and 10 months old'
lst=list(string.split())
lst1=[]
for i in lst :
  if(i.isdigit()):
      i=int(i)
      lst1.append(i)
if(len(lst1)!=0):
  avg=sum(lst1)/len(lst1)
else:
  avg=0

print(sum(lst1))
print(avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this:

```
a='Hello123, I am Hello World234'
a=a.split()
t=[int(''.join([j for j in k if j.isnumeric()])) for k in a if any(m.isnumeric() for m in k)]
if len(t)!=0:
    print(sum(t),sum(t)/len(t))
else:
    print(sum(t),sum(t))
```

Output:

```
357 178.5
```

Comment: It will give DivisionbyZero error if list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Convert str in a list using the `map()` function and then check if it is a digit. If it is then append it in a stack and count average and sum using stack.

```
total=0
avrage=0
stack=[]
line=list(map(str,input().split()))
    
for i in line:
    if i.isdigit():
        i=int(i)
        stack.append(i)
    
avrage=sum(stack) / len(stack)
total=sum(stack)
print(avrage)
print(total)
```

Comment: That won't work if the letters and numbers are fused