# How would one split line into an array of words and convert them to lowercase with Python?

Tags: python-3.x

How would one split line into an array of words and convert them to lowercase with Python? I am working with a TXT file. Below is my work thus far:

```
file_data = []

# ------------ Add your code below --------------

# We need to open the file

with open('/dsa/data/all_datasets/hamilton-federalist-548.txt', 'r') as file: 
# For each line in file
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        file_data.append(split_line)
        print(split_line)   
        
# We want to split that line into an array of words and convert them to lowercase

    
# [x.lower() for x in ["A","B","C"]] this example code will covert that list of letters to lowercase

print(file_data.lower())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a String to a List of Words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181763/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-words)

Comment: I was able to convert the list into an array of words. How would I convert them to lowercase from here? The print(file_data.lower()) is not converting the uppercase strings into lower case.

Comment: Convert the line to the lower case and _then_ split.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert them before adding them to the `file_data` list.

So instead of:

```
split_line = line.split(' ')
```

Try this:

```
split_line = [i.lower() for i in line.split(' ')]
```